# $ \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^1 e^{i\cdot n\cdot p(x)}~dx=0$ where $p(x)$ is a nonconstant polynomial with real coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

If $p(x)$ is a nonconstant polynomial with real coefficients, then how can we show that $$ \lim_{n\to \infty}  \int_0^1 e^{i\cdot n \cdot p(x)}~dx=0 ?$$

The integrand $e^{i \cdot n \cdot p(x)}$ is clearly bounded by $1$, but I can't apply the dominated convergence theorem because $\lim_{n\to \infty}e^{i \cdot n \cdot p(x)}$ does not necessarily exists. Any hints?

Comment: What is $inp(x)$?

Comment: Do you mean $i\cdot n$? Otherwise, I don't see any $n$ in the expression

Comment: @RhysHughes It  is $i \cdot n\cdot p(x)$ where $i=\sqrt{-1}$

Comment: @VIVID Yes you are right

Comment: Try it for $p(x)=x^k$ and recall Riemann Lebesgue.

Comment: I think this is relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251232/prove-lim-n-to-infty-int-01fxeinx3dx-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $\delta > 0$, let $[a,b] \subset [0,1]$ be an interval on which $p' > \delta$.
Then using the change of variable $t = p(x)$

$$ \int_a^b \exp(inp(x))\; dx = \int_{p(a)}^{p(b)} \frac{\exp(int)}{p'(p^{-1}(t))} \; dt $$
(where $p^{-1}$ is the inverse function to the restriction of $p$ to the interval $[a,b]$)
and this converges to $0$ as $n \to \infty$ by the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma.  Similarly for intervals on which $p' < -\delta$.  Now take $\epsilon \to 0+$

Given $\epsilon > 0$, after excluding a set of measure $< \epsilon$ containing the zeros of $p'$ we cover the rest by finitely many intervals on which, for some $\delta > 0$, $p' > \delta$ or $p' < -\delta$, and conclude that $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \left|\int_0^1 \exp(inp(x))\; dx \right| < \epsilon$$